# Fonts used on cover of this textbook series (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)

Tags: font-identification

I'm wondering what fonts are used on the cover of this textbook series: https://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/d/w/2/Algebraic-Geometry-SDL803985763-1-cda65.jpg. The author/title seem to be maybe in Arial, "Springer" is maybe in Times(?), and I'm at a loss for what the series name up top is in. (WhatTheFont didn't give anything definite for that one, and for the others gave lots of very similar results. Also, the first two I've eyeballed but would like to be sure on since it's important to me to get as close a match as possible.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can tell the author and title are Helvetica Bold, certainly not Arial.

[image]

The top one looks like Compacta Bold although I can't be 100% sure since the image quality is so bad. The x looks a bit wrong, however maybe the image is just so poor quality it's hard to tell.

[image]

The bottom Springer one is not detailed enough to tell for sure, but there's an EPS version of their logo [available on their website](https://www.springer.com/gp/about-springer/media), with the text converted to outlines, so you don't have to guess.

Comment: I was actually just looking into this. I found a cover image in way better resolution on google, made it black/white in Photoshop and uploaded it to whatthefont. I also find "Compacta Bold" to be the closest match, although not 100% similar. For example the "G" is more rounded in the original. But the books seems to be from the 1970s. Before digital typesetting. So the exact font might not be available in our times.

Comment: @Wolff - ah yes, always a possibility.

Comment: yes i think Compacta Bold is almost exactly it (everything seems right except "r"s have a slightly shorter hook on the cover, it seems...). thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The book series name:

Shortened letter spacing make low res images hopeless for automatic font identifiers. I found an ad of the same book series with sharper image. With it font identifiers gave good suggestions. It's the brown version in the next image. The black version is taken from Fontspring's Cataloque. It presents font family Compressa. actually the shown version is Compressa Bold.

[image]

Comment: this is good, thank you!